# Save more than 1 data of a variable in one id

Tags: php, mysql

I crawled a web, for example I crawled to get the authors (`$author`) and the link of authors. For one id, sometime, there are 2 authors, and when I save them in database, they will be separated in different id,

for example : I get `$author` and `$link` = `string(14) "Aaron M. Cohen" string(73) "http://example.com/Author/4279758" string(16) "William R. Hersh" string(68) "http://example.com/Author/299122"`

```
===========================================================
|id|web|      author    |            author_link          |
===========================================================
|1 | A |Aaron M. Cohen  |http://example.com/Author/4279758|
|2 | A |William R. Hersh|http://example.com/Author/299122 |
===========================================================
```

Is it possible to save them in one same id? How? thank you in advance :)
fyi, I wanna save them in one id, because of the next process is I want to inner join the table with other table that have same `web`. If there are two id in same `web`, they will be printed twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Create another table that actually contains the author and a fkey to the id in order to keep the database in [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).